# nil value in protocol delegation in tableview and customcell

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview

Im new in Swift, sorry.
I want push value from customcell class to TableViewController class. 
But always get "nil".

```
 protocol DetailsDelegate {
    func labelDelegateMethodWithString(controller: TableViewController) -> String }



class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


var delegate: DetailsDelegate?

@IBAction func butttonFunc(sender: UIButton) {

    let importNumber = delegate!.labelDelegateMethodWithString(self)

    println(importNumber)
}
```

and here my custom cell class:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate, DetailsDelegate {
    func labelDelegateMethodWithString(controller: TableViewController) -> String {
        return "efgfsd"
    }
```

What im doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: What line are you getting nil? Also, you never set your delegate.

Comment: Thanks man) the problem was in delegate. I forget about this question.